# List<String> cannot be converted to List<?>

Tags: java, generics

I have a builder class with a method that takes List of unknown type

```
public class A{
    private List<D<?>> data;
    public void setData(List<D<?>> data){
        this.data=data;
    }
}
public class D<T>{
        private List<T> data;
        public void setData(List<T> data){
            this.data=data;
        }
    }
```

Then in my caller class I have:

```
    public class B{
        private A a;

        public void apply(A a, List<D<String>> list){
            a.setData(list); //It shows an error
        }
    }
```

It is showing the following error:

> `List<String>` cannot be converted to `List<?>`

My understanding of unknown type was it should allow something basic like this. They are both java.util.List

Can someone explain why this is the case and what is the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

If we have,

```
public void apply(A a, List<D<String>> list){
    a.setData(list); //It shows an error
}
```

it always restricted that type of `D` instances should always be `String`s in the context of `apply()`. Because what we actually have in `a` instance of class `A` might be `List<D<Integer>>`.Compiler see this conflict and it doesn't allow to compile.

**Fix:**

```
public void apply(A a, List<D<?>> list){
    a.setData(list);
}
```

Because you are free to have any type for `T` in class `D`. *Unbounded* type parameter.

So, you could instantiate `D` instances as below:

```
D<Integer> intD = new D<Integer>();
D<String> stringD = new D<String>();
```

All these are completely acceptable according the class declaration of `D` *(Because of Unbounded type parameter)*.

If we take `stringD` instance, it has a `List` of `String`s.
Same like `intD` instance, it has a `List` of `Integer`s.

Answer (score 1):

Correct typing workarounds:

```
class A{
    private List<? extends D<?>> data;
    public void setData(List<? extends D<?>> data){
        this.data=data;
    }
}
```

or

```
class A<T> {
    private List<D<T>> data;
    public void setData(List<D<T>> data){
        this.data=data;
    }
}
class B{
    private A<String> a;

    public void apply(A<String> a, List<D<String>> list){
        a.setData(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What

```
public void apply(A a, List<D<String>> list){
    a.setData(list); // List<D<String>> cannot be converted to List<D<?>>
}
```

#### Why

If you were allowed to cast/convert `List<D<String>>` to `List<D<?>>`, then you could add a `D<Integer>` to the list, because it's allowed to contain a `D` of any type, but any code with a reference to that list will then have a list that contains a `D<Integer>` when it was expecting only `D<String>`.

#### Work around

As explained above, you can't cast directly to `List<D<?>>`, but you *can* use (what I call) a "magic double cast"; first to `List<?>` *then* to `List<D<?>>`:

```
a.setData((List<D<?>>)(List<?>)list); // compiles OK!
```

Of course this is an unsafe cast, so it's up to you to be sure that doing so won't cause problems.